# Best way to load 2000 files quickest in SSIS

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, netezza, flat-file

I currently am optimizing an SSIS package that processes approximately 2000 files when it runs and loads it into an ETL table. It is a simple foreach loop with fastload into a netezza table. Obviously, it takes quite a bit of time, mostly because each time one file is loaded there are a few other audit steps that need to happen before we can go right into the next file. I tried using `nzload` but again it didn't change much because the actually load of the file is quick, it's just the whole loop of 1 file x 2000 is a lot, which leads me to my question:

Is there an easy way to split this up into say 4 streams? All of the files are sitting in 1 directory (they are txt files), and have a integer ending. For instance, the naming convention would be `File1607120001`, and that ending number would just increment (Next would be `File1607120002` up to `File1607123000`, and then the 712 would change to 713 and it would reset going to 3000 again). Any special way I can trick the foreach numerator and do 4 separate streams all loading to the same table from the same directory?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a modification of the following two options to see how it works.

1. Parallel Processing in SSIS control flow and data flow.  Take a look
   at the following link: [Improve ETL Performance with SSIS Parallel Processing](https://www.dynamics101.com/ssis-parallel-processing/)
2. Concurrent Processing.  Take a look at the following two links: [Concurrent Processing in SSIS Part 1](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/70346/) and [Part 2](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/70347/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems there are numerous small files you are trying to load into NZ, it can be faster if you merge small files into one big file and instead to run a loop over each small file run it once for bigger file.

If you are not doing complex ETL process with SSIS then best option is compress small files and move it to NZ host then with shell script either merge small ones into one big file and nzload or awk last 4 chars of file name and get a modulo of 4 then put the file into threads bucket to process in parallel.